# DKIM is still declared as none

Tags: postfix-mta, dkim

I am  using the postfix mailserver and set that up for DKIM signing and changed the DNS record as TXT on my hoster. I followed these instructions exactly and checked them for 10 times:

https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setting-up-dkim-and-spf

But still when I test my mails it says

- dkim=**none** (message not signed)
- header.d=**none**

SPF and DMARC are marked as **pass**.

I get a score of **7.4/10** at mail-tester.com.

I restarted the server, postfix and opendkim. But nothing helped. Login via SSH postfix and opendkim are active.

I am now for 3 days on it but can not solve the issue. Do you guys have any idea what could be the problem? Could the HELO-Domain (Hostname of my server) be the problem? Because it is different to my Website domain.